# How to add a folder by name vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button2.Click

    Dim folderName As String = " WAP02"

    If Not Directory.Exists(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName) Then

        MessageBox.Show("Directory Does not Exist. Program will create a Directory")
        Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName)
        MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Directory already existed")
    End If

End Sub
```

I create a button to add folder into my folder(folder test). If i have already have WAP01 in my folder(folder test) , how should i write a routine to get WAP02 when i click the button, and if i click button again i will get WAP03 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button2.Click

Dim folderName As String = "WAP0"
Dim folderUniqueNumber AS Integer = 1

While Directory.Exists(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
    folderUniqueNumber +=1
End While

If folderUniqueNumber = 1 Then

    MessageBox.Show("Directory Does not Exist. Program will create a Directory")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
    MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")

Else
    MessageBox.Show("Directory already existed. Directory number incremented to: " & folderUniqueNumber)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
    MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")
End If

End Sub
```

A While loop checks if the directory exists, and if so adds 1 to the folder number. Then, the directory is made with the newly created unique folder name, plus some little messages indicating to the user if the folder had to be incremented in the first place.

Edit:

After reading the other comments I think this is what you need. It successfully creates numbered directories from "WAP01" all the way through "WZP20". If the preceding directory does not exceed 4GB in size in all its subdirectories then it does not create the next directory. Unlike Enes's solution, it functions appropriately even if the directories are not created all in one session (if you open the application, press the button a few times, close it, reopen it, press the button a few more times), or similarly if the directories are created or deleted outside of the program.

If you run out of letters (after you use up all the possible "WZP" directories), the program should give a message indicating such and then exit.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim folderPrevious As String = Nothing
    Dim folderLetterAsNum As Integer = 65
    Dim folderName As String = "W" & Chr(folderLetterAsNum) & "P0"
    Dim folderUniqueNumber As Integer = 1

    While Directory.Exists(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
        folderPrevious = folderName & folderUniqueNumber
        If folderUniqueNumber < 20 Then
            folderUniqueNumber += 1
        ElseIf folderLetterAsNum < 90
            folderUniqueNumber = 1
            folderLetterAsNum += 1
        Else
            MsgBox("You are out of characters!")
            Me.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If folderUniqueNumber < 10 Then
            folderName = "W" & Chr(folderLetterAsNum) & "P0"
        Else
            folderName = "W" & Chr(folderLetterAsNum) & "P"
        End If
    End While

    If folderPrevious Is Nothing OrElse FldrSize("C:\folder test\" & folderPrevious) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) > 4 Then

        If folderUniqueNumber = 1 And folderLetterAsNum = 65 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Directory Does not Exist. Program will create a Directory")
            Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
            MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Directory already existed. Directory directory created as: " & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName & folderUniqueNumber)
            MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Directory was not over 4GB. No directory created!")
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FldrSize(ByVal dPath As String)

    Dim size As Integer = 0


    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(dPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")
        Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(foundFile)
        size += fInfo.Length
    Next

    Return size

End Function
```

Hope that helps!

I cannot comment on Enes's answer directly (I don't have sufficient reputation), but his solution is unfortunately flawed. Specifically when it creates the folder "WAP20" it will attempt to immediately also create "WBP1". This is because it cannot properly check the size of "WAP20" in the second IF structure. Also, if you do not create the directories entirely in the same session, the program will not function appropriately, or if the folders are created or deleted outside of the program. It is hard to describe, but I am afraid it is not a sound solution in that regard.

Comment: The code runs perfect. Another question bro. If i want to change WAP the file name to WBP, for instance, if i click button, they will give WAP01 WAP 02 WAP 03, then WBP 01, WBP02, WBP03,WBP04, then WCP01 etc. IS that possible to solve it out?

Comment: Are you asking how you might make the program automatically transition from "WAP" to "WBP" after some number of "WAP" folders? Or are you asking if the code can be altered to handle any sequence of characters instead of "WAP" in the same manner?

Answer (score 0):

First,you need this.

```
Imports System.IO
```

Then here is your code.

```
Dim num As Integer = 1
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim folderName As String = "WAP" + num.ToString
    If Not Directory.Exists(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Directory Does not Exist. Program will create a Directory")
        Directory.CreateDirectory(" C:\folder test" & "\" & folderName)
        MessageBox.Show("Directory created successfully")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Directory already existed")
    End If
    num += 1
End Sub
```

It increses directory names then creates them.Here is an output[image]

Comment: thanks bro. That solved my problems so far. One more question. If i add my folder like WAP1 WAP2, WBP1, WBP2,WCP1,WCP2. not only the number. Can you do that ? cheers

Comment: You need to set some variables A-Z.When WZP comes,what'is next ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: if i click button, they will give WAP01 WAP 02 WAP 03, then WBP 01, WBP02, WBP03,WBP04, then WCP01 etc

Comment: And do you want to work with two number (1 and 2) ? WAP1,WAP2,WBP1,WBP2...Do you need WAP3,WBP3 ?

Comment: I mean how many number or letter are you going to use ? A to Z , 0 to 9999 ?

Comment: as long as the folder is 4GB, we move to next one. 0 to 20, 20 seems maximum. WAP, WBP, WCP only three

Comment: yes. if WAP0 is less than 4GB, then we don't have WAP1, if WAP is over 4GB we have WAP1.

Comment: Do the WAP1,WAP2... have subdirectory ?

Comment: no subdiretory. only image files and i already got the size of all the images

Comment: Alright I made a program that controls if bigger than 4 gb,then create new dir.It only creates WAP1,WAP2,WAP3...Do you really need WBP ?

Comment: i can do WBP myself. Could you please show me your code for 4gb bigger. Cheeres

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim size1 As Long = 4294967297
Dim num As Integer = 0
Dim folderName As String
Dim folderName2 As String
Dim dInfo As DirectoryInfo
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If num < 21 And num >= 0 Then
        folderName2 = "WAP" + (num - 1).ToString
        If Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName2) Then
            dInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\folder test\" & folderName2)
            size1 = dInfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(Function(file) file.Length)
        End If
        folderName = "WAP" + num.ToString
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName) And size1 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) > 4 Then

            MsgBox("Directory does not exist or directory size is bigger than 4GB. Program will create a new directory.")
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\folder test\" & folderName)
            MsgBox("Directory created successfully")
            num += 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Directory already existed and smaller then 4GB.")
        End If

    End If

    If num < 41 And num >= 21 Then
        folderName2 = "WBP" + (num - 21).ToString
        If Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName2) Then
            dInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\folder test\" & folderName2)
            size1 = dInfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(Function(file) file.Length)
        End If
        folderName = "WBP" + (num - 20).ToString
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName) And size1 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) > 4 Then

            MsgBox("Directory does not exist or directory size is bigger than 4GB. Program will create a new directory.")
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\folder test\" & folderName)
            MsgBox("Directory created successfully")
            num += 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Directory already existed and smaller then 4GB.")
        End If
    End If
    If num < 61 And num >= 41 Then
        folderName2 = "WCP" + (num - 41).ToString
        If Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName2) Then
            dInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\folder test\" & folderName2)
            size1 = dInfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(Function(file) file.Length)
        End If
        folderName = "WCP" + (num - 40).ToString
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\folder test\" & folderName) And size1 / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) > 4 Then

            MsgBox("Directory does not exist or directory size is bigger than 4GB. Program will create a new directory.")
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\folder test\" & folderName)
            MsgBox("Directory created successfully")
            num += 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Directory already existed and smaller then 4GB.")
        End If
    End If


End Sub




End Class
```

When you press `Button2`,it makes WAP0 first.If WAP0 size is bigger than 4GB,creates WAP1,then WAP2,WAP3.When it reachs WAP20 it continues on WBP0 until reach WBP20.Then starts WCP series. You can add WDP on your own.Look at differences and get what changes everytime.Good luck !